# React - creating dom from simple object tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to represent DOM in json and come across React on this page.

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html

```
{
  type: 'button',
  props: {
    className: 'button button-blue',
    children: {
      type: 'b',
      props: {
        children: 'OK!'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Is there any way, we can use the multi level DOM representation like the one below to render components?** I have tried many ways, not succeed yet!

```
const DeleteAccount = () => ({
  type: 'div',
  props: {
    children: [{
      type: 'p',
      props: {
        children: 'Are you sure?'
      }
    }, {
      type: DangerButton,
      props: {
        children: 'Yep'
      }
    }, {
      type: Button,
      props: {
        color: 'blue',
        children: 'Cancel'
      }
   }]
 }
});
```

I guess I'm not trying to use React for it's purpose, But, will be great if I can use this DOM representation for my simple static HTML strings.

Also, I haven't understood how it is written there. Is it ES6?

JS fiddle -  https://jsfiddle.net/midhunanew/Lszmmsr1/2/

Comment: Oh, no! React blog has a syntax error which made me think this is not ES6!

Answer (score 0):

This is [**JSX**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) syntax. and this would be transpile to JavaScript syntax by tranpiler(e.g [Babel](http://babeljs.io/).)

And if you want to code with (or read) the javascript syntax(not recommend), you can use the [babel playground](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=var%20Ele%20%3D%20React.createClass(%7B%0A%20%20render%3A%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3Ehello%20world%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)%0AReactDOM.render(%3CEle%20%2F%3E%2C%20document.getElementById('test'))%3B) to try it out.

For example, if your code is,

```
var Ele = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>hello world</div>
    );
  }
})
ReactDOM.render(<Ele />, document.getElementById('test'));
```

After transpile you will get,

```
'use strict';

var Ele = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Ele',

  render: function render() {
    return React.createElement(
      'div',
      null,
      'hello world'
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Ele, null), document.getElementById('test'));
```

And it will be much more easier for you to write the JSX structure and use this playground to transpile them.

Hope this would help. : )

---

Update for `() => {}`. This is [Arrow Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
Basically it another format of anonymous function.(Without confusing `this`)

Comment: you were telling this is JSX syntax? **const DeleteAccount = () => ({**

Comment: No, this is [es6 arrow expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). I was talking about the render part actually. I better update my answer.

Comment: Actually, my question was to use object representation with React? Is that not clear from it? I'm not good at English. Please see the highlighted part.

Comment: My bad, I think in my sample code, you can read render part(2nd one).

Comment: No, it is not using an object in `React.createElement`